# Make Node.js use http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy environment variables

Tags: node.js, http, proxy

I have a node server and based on some recent infrastructure changes, I need to make sure all outbound requests are going through a Squid proxy EXCEPT for traffic to hosts listed in the NO_PROXY environment variable.

Setting HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY doesn't seem to affect the node server's behavior, but I need a way to do this without having to manually edit libraries.  I have ~10 libraries that reach out to external services that need to respect this proxying behavior.

Is there some other way I can globally set proxying behavior including respecting NO_PROXY?

Comment: have you found solution for this?

Comment: For Node.js v12 and above you can use https://github.com/gajus/global-agent. For older version of Node.js you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-tunnel-ng.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, the Node.js runtime does not support configuring HTTP proxying using environment variables out of the box (see [nodejs/node#8381](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8381) and [nodejs/node#15620](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15620)).  Request library support is mixed:

- `request` does ([request/request#1096](https://github.com/request/request/pull/1096))
- `node-fetch` does not ([node-fetch/node-fetch#195](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/195)) (see below)
- `got` does not ([sindresorhus/got#79](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/issues/79)) (see below)

Any library which provides a way to pass an [`http.Agent`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) which can support environmentally-configured proxies, such as:

- [`tunnel`](https://github.com/koichik/node-tunnel)
- [`proxy-agent`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-proxy-agent)
- [`global-agent`](https://github.com/gajus/global-agent)

For example:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import ProxyAgent from 'proxy-agent';

const response = await fetch('https://example.com', { agent: new ProxyAgent() });
const body = await response.text();
```

If you can not pass an `Agent`, or can't modify the code at all, you may want to consider [`global-agent`](https://github.com/gajus/global-agent) which can be used as a pre-loaded module to proxy all requests (configured by the `GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY` environment variable):

```sh
export GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com
node --require global-agent/bootstrap mycode.js
```

Alternatively, if your system supports `LD_PRELOAD` or `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`, you could use a general-purpose proxifier such as [ProxyChains-NG](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) (or the original [ProxyChains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/)).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone arrives here, it seems it was already added to request.js in https://github.com/request/request/pull/1096

Comment: Request is a deprecated project now.